Center alignment in row of LazyVGrid
I am creating a LazyVGrid with 2 columns. I want it so that if there is only one item in a row, then it goes to the center of the row. I tried using an HStack with a Spacer, but it doesn't push it to the center. Anyone knows how to do it?
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 35) {
    ForEach(pets) { pet in
        VStack {
            Image(pet.species.rawValue)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 80, height: 80)

            Text(pet.name)
                .poppinsBold(size: 16)
        }
    }

    HStack {

        if pets.hasEvenNumber {
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }

        Button {
            addPetSheet = true
        } label: {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)

                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                }

                Text("Add")
                    .poppinsBold(size: 16)
            }
        }
    }
}


If you are expecting to be showing a large number of pets then you will presumably put the grid inside a ScrollView. If the button is in the last row, you will be forcing the user to scroll all the way to the bottom to find it. For this reason alone, it might be better if the button was outside the grid (and outside the ScrollView).
Then again, if we are talking about the pets in a household then there may not be such a large number after all. In this case, there is probably no need to use a lazy grid at all, except that it makes it easy to build the grid using a ForEach to iterate over the array.
→ So instead of using a LazyVGrid, you could consider using a Grid. Then you will be able to set .gridCellColumns(2) on the content of the last row. This modifier only works for the rows of a Grid, not for a LazyVGrid.
For building the rows of the Grid, you might want to iterate over the array in pairs. The post Iterate over collection two at a time in Swift shows ways of doing this.
So here is an adaption of your example that uses a Grid instead of a LazyVGrid, with the button in the last grid row.

The array can be converted to an array of pet pairs by the following computed property:

private var petsInPairs: [(firstPet: Pet, secondPet: Pet?)] {
    stride(from: 0, to: pets.endIndex, by: 2).map {
        (pets[$0], $0 < pets.index(before: pets.endIndex) ? pets[$0.advanced(by: 1)] : nil)
    }
}


To avoid code duplication, the part that builds the view for one pet can be factored out into a separate function:

private func petCell(pet: Pet) -> some View {
    VStack {
        Image(pet.species.rawValue)
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)

        Text(pet.name)
            .poppinsBold(size: 16)
    }
}


While we're at it, let's factor out the add button too:

private var addButton: some View {
    Button {
        addPetSheet = true
    } label: {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    .foregroundStyle(.gray)

                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .foregroundStyle(.white)
                    .font(.title)
            }

            Text("Add")
                .poppinsBold(size: 16)
        }
    }
}


The grid can then built using the parts above:

ScrollView {
    Grid(horizontalSpacing: 35, verticalSpacing: 35) {
        ForEach(Array(petsInPairs.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { rowId, petPair in
            GridRow {
                petCell(pet: petPair.firstPet)
                if let secondPet = petPair.secondPet {
                    petCell(pet: secondPet)
                }
            }
        }
        GridRow {
            addButton
                .gridCellColumns(2) //  THIS SOLVES THE ALIGNMENT ISSUE
        }
    }
}

In fact, a Grid works differently to a LazyVGrid. The documentation to gridCellColumns explains:

As a convenience you can cause a view to span all of the Grid columns by placing the view directly in the content closure of the Grid, outside of a GridRow, and omitting the modifier.

So the last row of the grid could just be added as addButton:
Grid(horizontalSpacing: 35, verticalSpacing: 35) {
    ForEach(Array(petsInPairs.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { rowId, petPair in
        // ...
    }
    addButton
}


If something can be in the centre of a 2-column grid, it's no longer a grid.
You should place the add button outside of the LazyVGrid when the number of pets is even. Make sure the parent of the LazyVStack has a centre alignment.
LazyVGrid(...) {
    ForEach(pets) { pet in
        ...
    }
    if !pets.count.isMultiple(of: 2) {
        AddButton(...)
    }
}
if pets.count.isMultiple(of: 2) {
    AddButton(...)
}

Here is a more complete example - I have added a matched geometry effect on the two add buttons, so the animation looks natural.
struct Pet: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let name: String
    let image: String
    var id: String { name }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var pets = [
        Pet(name: "Foo", image: "cat"),
        Pet(name: "Bar", image: "dog"),
        Pet(name: "Baz", image: "bird"),
        Pet(name: "Goo", image: "cat"),
        Pet(name: "Gar", image: "dog"),
        Pet(name: "Boo", image: "bird"),
        Pet(name: "Last", image: "cat"),
    ]
    
    @Namespace var ns
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [.init(.fixed(80)), .init(.fixed(80))]) {
                ForEach(pets) { pet in
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: pet.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        Text(pet.name)
                    }
                }
                if !pets.count.isMultiple(of: 2) {
                    addButton
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "add", in: ns)
                }
            }
            if pets.count.isMultiple(of: 2) {
                addButton
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "add", in: ns)
            }
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var addButton: some View {
        AddButton {
            withAnimation {
                pets.append(Pet(name: "New", image: "dog"))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddButton: View {
    let action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                        .foregroundStyle(.gray)
                    
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                }
                
                Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}

If your grid has more columns, consider using a custom Layout instead. For example, an HFlow with horizontalAlignment: .center.
